# Material design CSS styling issue

Tags: materialize

I have a hyperlink that opens a modal dialog:

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">{{Modal}}</a>
```

The styling makes it appear as a button while I want it as a plain text. IF I remove `class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger"`, the text disappear completely. Replacing it with a different class

```
.txt {
    color: white;
 }
```

did not work - text still disappears. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Did you try to just keep the `modal-trigger` class like this : `<a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal1">{{Modal}}</a>` ?

Comment: Its not disappearing mate, do you have any styles which already exist for `<a>` tags?

Comment: removing everything except `modal-trigger` did not work - it removed the text as well. On the contrary, removing `btn` part worked great. Now the only issue is extra spacing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `waves-effect waves-light btn` classes. This should leave you with:

```
<a class="modal-trigger" href="#modal1">{{Modal}}</a>
```

This will remove the button styling and leave you with simple text that triggers your modal.

Comment: removing everything except `modal-trigger` did not work - it removed the text as well. On the contrary, removing `btn` part worked great. Now the only issue is extra spacing